# Combine a list of multiple dictionaries into on single dict based on condition

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I want to merge some of the dictionaries, condition is whenever they have the same value in `age` and `experience` then I need to merge all the `dict` and keep the dict that doesn't below to this condition.

**I have the following list of dictionaries:**

```
lst = [
        {
            "Game": "Lego",
            "players": [         
            {   "training":"2",
                "Age": "28",
                "Experience": "no",
                "Score": [
                    {
                        "Alicia": 87
                    }
                ]
            },
                {
                    "Age": "20",
                    "Experience": "yes",
                    "Score": [
                        {
                            "Alex": 230
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Age": "20",
                    "Experience": "yes",
                    "Score": [
                        {
                            "juana": 275
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "season": "summer"

        }
    ]
```

**The output should look like this:**

```
[
        {
            "Game": "Lego",
            "players": [
            {   "training":"2",
                "Age": "28",
                "Experience": "no",
                "Score": [
                    {
                        "Alicia": 87
                    }
                ]
            },         
                {
                    "Age": "20",
                    "Experience": "yes",
                    "Score": [
                        {
                            "Alex": 230
                        },
                        {
                            "juana": 275
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "season": "summer"
        }
    ]
```

I'm blocked in checking if the age/experience are equal after this step.

```
for d in lst:
        for i, sd in enumerate(d['players']):
            d['players'][i] = {k: v for k, v in d['players'][i].items()}
```

**Note:**

- i have multiple dict not only 2
- There is some keys existing in some dict e.g `training`

Comment: What specifically is your question? Can you make a simpler example that still demonstrates the problem you are facing?

Comment: Why do you want `"Score": [{"Alex": 230}, {"juana": 275}]` as a result and not just `"Score": {"Alex": 230, "juana": 275}`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes i need this structure `"Score": [{"Alex": 230}, {"juana": 275}]` my question is howa can i compare the values of age and experience in each dict and if they are equal how can i combine it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this code is very messy and could be done much better, but I think it does the job:

```
    result_lst = []

for game_dict in lst:

    result_dict = {}
    result_dict['Game'] = game_dict['Game']
    result_dict['players'] = []
    result_dict['season'] = game_dict['season']

    for player_dict1 in game_dict['players']:

        starting_idx = game_dict['players'].index(player_dict1) + 1

        for player_dict2 in game_dict['players'][starting_idx:]:

            if player_dict1['Age'] == player_dict2['Age'] and player_dict1['Experience'] == player_dict2['Experience']:

                age = player_dict1['Age']
                experience = player_dict1['Experience']

                for result_player in result_dict['players']:

                    if age == result_player['Age']:

                        if player_dict1['Score'][0] not in result_player['Score']:
                            result_player['Score'].append(player_dict1['Score'][0])

                        if player_dict2['Score'][0] not in result_player['Score']:
                            result_player['Score'].append(player_dict2['Score'][0])

                        break
                
                else:

                    players_dict = {'Age': age,
                                    'Experience': experience,
                                    'Score': [player_dict1['Score'][0],
                                            player_dict2['Score'][0],
                                    ]
                    }

                    result_dict['players'].append(players_dict)
    
    in_result_dict = True

    for player_dict in game_dict['players']:
        
        for result_players in result_dict['players']:
            for result_player in result_players['Score']:
                
                if player_dict['Score'][0] == result_player:
                    in_result_dict = False
                    break

        if in_result_dict:
            result_dict['players'].append(player_dict)

    result_lst.append(result_dict)


print(result_lst)
```

Also note that this way of storing information is too redundant and makes it hard to access the data and iterate over it, please consider refactoring it.

Anyway, the output is:

```
[{'Game': 'Lego', 
'players': [{'Age': '20', 
            'Experience': 'yes', 
            'Score': [{'Alex': 230}, {'juana': 275}]}, 
            
            {'Age': '28', 
                'Experience': 'yes', 
                'Score': [{'Alicia': 987}]}], 
'season': 'summer'}]
```

Comment: thanks luis, yes score its a mistake from my part. there  is a misunderstood actually what is to regroup the dict that have the same age and the same experience which are not always 20 and yes

Comment: Okay. Then, if nothing else is left, there is your answer.

Comment: thanks Luis but i I still Haven't Found What I'm Looking For !

Comment: I just updated it, take a look at it, I think it is what you need :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort Luis G, but i think that this will not work because i need to merge identical dict and keep also the one which is different

Comment: This way you get a parsed copy of your list of dictionaries that your can later use to compare it to the original. If this does not serve, please, reformulate your question so I can help you better.

Comment: Yes i edited my post Luis G, i will be grateful if you could help me

Comment: See if that big chunk I made helps you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @LuisG. thanks but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. Here I try to

1 convert the players list to dataframe
2 Then do a group by on the df to match for Age and experience and get Score.
3 Convert this dataframe back to dict, which is later updated to the original `lst`

```
import pandas as pd
lst = [] #Replace this with your list.
players = lst[0]['players']
print('Players before update\n', players)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(players)
df_new = df.groupby(['Age','Experience'])['Score'].sum().reset_index()
players = df_new.to_dict('records')    
print('Players after update \n', players)    

print('lst before update\n', lst)
lst[0]['players'] = players
print('lst after update \n', lst)
```

**Output:**

```
Players before update
 [{'Age': '20', 'Experience': 'yes', 'Score': [{'Alex': 230}]}, {'Age': '20', 'Experience': 'yes', 'Score': [{'juana': 275}]}]
Players after update 
 [{'Age': '20', 'Experience': 'yes', 'Score': [{'Alex': 230}, {'juana': 275}]}]
lst before update
 [{'Game': 'Lego', 'players': [{'Age': '20', 'Experience': 'yes', 'Score': [{'Alex': 230}]}, {'Age': '20', 'Experience': 'yes', 'Score': [{'juana': 275}]}], 'season': 'summer'}]
lst after update 
 [{'Game': 'Lego', 'players': [{'Age': '20', 'Experience': 'yes', 'Score': [{'Alex': 230}, {'juana': 275}]}], 'season': 'summer'}]
```